# "Why the loading values and CSV file values showing different ?"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I loaded a CSV file in pandas data frame but it is showing only 0 and 1 values where the original CSV files have different values.

CSV file:

```
0 1.11468541e-03 8.55032558e-04
```

DataFrame showing:

```
0 0 1
```

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("features_3.csv")
```

Comment: Please let me know if I may provide anything else

Comment: what's the result of `dataset.iloc[0,1]`?

Comment: It is showing the actual value '0.0011146854130653211' but in the data frame it showing 0.

Comment: then just change the display precision of your dataframe `pd.set_option('precision', 6)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df
= pd.read_csv("path/file", float_precision='round_trip')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html

Comment: Adding some explanation makes answer better, also change `“ ”` quotes.